# Selecting random line from array c

Tags: arrays, c, linux

So far I have read all my data into an array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {
int i=0;
char* string[100];
char line[100];

FILE *file; 
file = fopen("plates.txt", "r"); 

while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file)!=NULL) {
printf("%s",line);

string[i]=line;
i++;
}

fclose(file);
return 0;
}
```

but i want to now select a random line of my array and print it. All lines need to have an equal chance of being selected but they can only be selected once. Im not too sure how to do this...

Thank you in advance

Comment: The code shown is incomplete and has syntax errors. Please show real and complete code. To get a random line you just need to get a random index. There are many posts already that describe how to generate a random number in a given range.

Comment: user17276226, should longer lines have a greater chance of being selected than short ones or are all lines equal?

Comment: All lines need to have an equal chance of being selected, they are all the same size because they are number plates but they can only be selected once.

Comment: So what prevents you from generating a number in the range `0` to `i` to use as the array index?

Comment: It's worth knowing that selecting a random input like this does *not* require reading all the input into an array.  It's perfectly straightforward to make the choice as you're reading.  See [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/One_of_n_lines_in_a_file), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling), and [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_algorithm_S).

Answer (score 0):

Please be mindful of this line `string[i]=line` as it makes all the array entries in `string` that you set all point to the last line read which is not what you want and it's pretty important to understand that.

That said, here's a solution to the problem that assumes we can just store all the lines in memory and on the stack:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 128
#define MAX_LINE_COUNT 1000

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char lines[MAX_LINE_COUNT][MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    int numLines = 0;
    
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing file name\n");     
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        while (fgets(lines[numLines++], MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fp)) {
            printf("%03d> %s", numLines, lines[numLines-1]);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        srand (time(NULL));
        int randomIndex = rand() % numLines;
        printf("Selected random line #%d> %s", randomIndex+1, lines[randomIndex]);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "file '%s' not found\n", argv[1]);      
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

And the corresponding output:

```
➜  ~ gcc random-line.c && ./a.out random-line.c 
001> #include <stdio.h>
002> #include <stdlib.h>
003> #include <string.h>
004> #include <time.h>
005> 
006> #define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 128
007> #define MAX_LINE_COUNT 1000
008> 
009> int main(int argc, char **argv) {
010>     char lines[MAX_LINE_COUNT][MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
011>    int numLines = 0;
012>     
013>     if (argc < 2) {
014>        fprintf(stderr, "missing file name\n");     
015>        return EXIT_FAILURE;
016>     }
017>    
018>     FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
019>     if (fp != NULL) {
020>        while (fgets(lines[numLines++], MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fp)) {
021>             printf("%03d> %s", numLines, lines[numLines-1]);
022>        }
023>        fclose(fp);
024>        srand (time(NULL));
025>        int randomIndex = rand() % numLines;
026>        printf("Selected random line #%d> %s", randomIndex+1, lines[randomIndex]);
027>    } else {
028>        fprintf(stderr, "file '%s' not found\n", argv[1]);      
029>        return EXIT_FAILURE;
030>    }
031> }
Selected random line #2> #include <stdlib.h>
```